# jquery cross domain ajax requests - IE8 and IE9 - YouTube API v3 - jsonp only?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, youtube-api, cross-domain

I just re-factored a bunch of code to connect to the YouTube API version 3 to find out that none of my ajax calls were working on IE8 and IE9. This had to do with how these versions of IE make cross domain ajax requests (they use MS XDomainRequest, which is not supported in jquery).

My old code was making jsonp requests and it worked on IE8 and IE9. My new code was making regular json requests eg: `$.ajax({dataType:'json', ...})` instead. I didn't realize that this would not work in IE8 and IE9.

One downside of making jsonp requests is that you cannot capture timeouts through the error callback of the ajax request because the server never responds, which means your callback will never get called. The way I handle this is (is there a better way??):

```
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    // a timeout occurred after 30 seconds
}, 30000);

$.ajax({
    url: url + 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/... &callback=?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // success!
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        o.fnError(getAjaxError(xhr));
    }
});
```

**My question is:** is this the best way to make calls into the YouTube API v3 using jquery and ajax?

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Data API v3 requires you to make GET requests using HTTPS. It will not work at all using HTTP requests. If the page that you are making the GET request from is using HTTP, then an XDomainRequest implementation will not work. XDomainRequest requires that the protocols match, so it is a pointless exercise trying to implement it unless your pages are served from HTTPS.

Comment: Interesting... my I typically don't use SSL in my dev environment, but the production environment is all SSL. I'll have to setup SSL and do some testing. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is right. if datatype is jsonp they dont use the XDomainRequest-Object, they use Script-tags and a callback-function. For me this is working with a HTTP-Site trying to access YT(HTTPS). I also set crossdomain to true

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you cannot use XDomainRequest in this case.  Either forget about jQuery when making cross-origin ajax requests in IE9 and IE8 (and use XDomainRequest directly), or use an XDomainRequest wrapper for jQuery, such as https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest.  No need to use JSONP here.

Note that if an XDomainRequest fails, no reason will be provided.  The onerror callback function doesn't take/is not passed any parameters.

Comment: I don't want to make XDomainRequests along side my jquery ajax requests. I tried that library but it doesn't work - not sure why, but it does require that the server sends back a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Maybe youtube is not returning that header.

Comment: If you don't want to use XDomainRequest directly and/or you aren't able to get it to work, then your only option is JSONP (assuming that is supported by the YouTube API).

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, but I would like to hear from some people who have integrated the youtube api v3 using jquery ajax.

Comment: MoonScript still does not support calls from http to https, so the moonscript suggestion will not work for youtube api calls from http. Youtube api calls must be https.